# PHP password_verify not working need to get result DOMAIN SPECIFIC

Tags: php, mysql, hash

So in my function I have the connection, the query which will result in 1 row and 1 column displayed. I then want to run the `password_verify()` This is where I am struggling. As the first parameter I have placed `$pass` which is user entered but then I need to get the result from the database to place in the 2nd parameter.

How would I do this?

```
function login($user, $pass){
    $conn = connect();
    $query = "SELECT password FROM account WHERE username = '$user' AND password = '$pass'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)=== 1){
        password_verify($pass, "$row[password]");
        session_start();
```

Comment: Because in db you store hashed password?

Comment: Wow... You should read a PHP-book or something..

Comment: Forget to fetch data form query result

Comment: `password_verify` returns true or false - you can't just run it and hope for a magical result

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When someone registers on your website, you have to use de built-in PHP function password_hash(). Also, I suggest naming it "password_hash" in your database and not "password" as to avoid confusion.

When someone tries to log in on your website, you have to use the built-in PHP password_verify() to compare the hashed password with the password.

```
// Login function
function login($user, $pass)
{
  // Search the user by username
  $conn = connect();
  $query = "SELECT password_hashed FROM account WHERE username = '$user'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

  if (mysqli_fetch_row($result))
  {
    // We found the user, check if password is correct
    if(password_verify($pass, $result["password_hashed"]))
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    // We didn't find the user
    return false;
  }
}
```

-Why should you hash the password when you store it into the database? Because when you store the password without hashing, the password in the database is exactly the same like what the user types in when registering. So when a hacker gets into the database, he sees the passwords of every user. If you hash the password, PHP makes the password into something completely else, that way when a hacker gets into the database he doesn't see the password but something completely else.

-The password_verify function is definitely the way to go when a user logs in. Just don't forget to add extra security when you enter data you receive from a user (through $_POST, $_GET, $_SESSION, ...) because when a user types in the follow name: **my name" DROP TABLES account;** they will delete all account informations.

Comment: You make the point (quite rightly) about not trusting user supplied data and still your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: That is because the question is about password_verify() not working, and not SQL injection.

Comment: People are lazy. They will simply copy and paste your code.

Comment: The function itself doesn't use $_GET or $_POST data. If he chooses to do so and finishes his script, it will be vulnerable but at least he saw an example of how easy it is to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If you do everything right your `password` field in a `account` table stores **hashed** password.

And argument `$pass` of a function is a plain password, I suppose.

So, your query

```
SELECT password FROM account WHERE username = '$user' AND password = '$pass'
```

will **NEVER** find any user, as you try to find user by plain password.

In addition - your `$row` variable is **not defined**.

What's the solution:

```
function login($user, $pass){
    $conn = connect();
    // do not add password to query
    $query = "SELECT password FROM account WHERE username = '$user'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) === 1){
        // define $row
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        // set proper quotes and compare password 
        // from db with password input by user            
        if (password_verify($pass, $row["password"])) {
            // do something if password is correct
            session_start();
```

And of course, instead of passing values directly to query, start using **prepared statements**.

Comment: You should lead by example and modify the code to use prepared statements. Many people will simply copy and paste it without reading your last remark.